# Loop in Jquery after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this script that is working but it return only 1 post from DB table.

I need that all posts of the table is displayed on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
(function update() {
$.ajax({
  url:"getposts",
  type: "get",  
  data: "{}",
  success: function(data){
    var res = data;
    $.each(res[0], function(index, value) {
        $('#prova').html($('<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 item">\
          <div class="timeline-block">\
              <div class="panel panel-default">\
                <div class="panel-heading">\
                  <div class="media">\
                    <div class="media-left">\
                      <a href="">\
                        <img src="http://bookstar.me/uploads/users/paolo.jpg" width="50px" class="media-object">\
                          </a>\
                        </div>\
                    <div class="media-body">\
                      <a href="#" class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="icon-reply-all-fill fa fa-2x "></i></a>\
                         <a href="">Paolo</a>\
                      <span>1/08/2016</span>\
                 </div>\
                  </div>\
                </div>\
                <div class="panel-body">\
                  <p>'+ value.post +'</p>\
                </div>\
                <div class="view-all-comments">\
                  <a href="#">\
                    <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> View all</a>\
                  <span>10 comments</span>\
                </div>\
                <ul class="comments">\
                  <li class="media">\
                    <div class="media-left">\
                      <a href="">\
                        <img src="http://bookstar.me/backend/bookstar/images/people/50/guy-5.jpg" class="media-object"></a>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="media-body">\
                      <div class="pull-right dropdown" data-show-hover="li">\
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="toggle-button">\
                          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>\
                        </a>\
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
                          <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>\
                          <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>\
                        </ul>\
                      </div>\
                      <a href="" class="comment-author pull-left">Bill D.</a>\
                      <span>Hi Mary, Nice Party</span>\
                      <div class="comment-date">21st September</div>\
                    </div>\
                  </li>\
                  <li class="media">\
                    <div class="media-left">\
                      <a href="">\
                        <img src="http://bookstar.me/backend/bookstar/images/people/50/woman-5.jpg" class="media-object">\
                      </a>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="media-body">\
                      <div class="pull-right dropdown" data-show-hover="li">\
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="toggle-button">\
                          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>\
                        </a>\
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
                          <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>\
                          <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>\
                        </ul>\
                      </div>\
                      <a href="" class="comment-author pull-left">Mary</a>\
                      <span>Thanks Bill</span>\
                      <div class="comment-date">2 days</div>\
                    </div>\
                  </li>\
                  <li class="media">\
                    <div class="media-left">\
                      <a href="">\
                        <img src="http://bookstar.me/backend/bookstar/images/people/50/guy-5.jpg" class="media-object"></a>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="media-body">\
                      <div class="pull-right dropdown" data-show-hover="li">\
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="toggle-button">\
                          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>\
                        </a>\
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">\
                          <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>\
                          <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>\
                        </ul>\
                      </div>\
                      <a href="" class="comment-author pull-left">Bill D.</a>\
                      <span>What time did it finish?</span>\
                      <div class="comment-date">14 min</div>\
                    </div>\
                  </li>\
                  <li class="comment-form">\
                    <div class="input-group">\
                      <span class="input-group-btn">\
               <a href="" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i></a>\
            </span>\
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" />\
                    </div>\
                  </li>\
                </ul>\
              </div>\
            </div>\
            </div>'));
    });
  }
}).then(function() {           // on completion, restart
   setTimeout(update, 1000);  // function refers to itself
});
})();
```

Any help is apprecited.

Comment: I not want to append (with .append it work as well) i want to refresh content of the page

Comment: Instead this res[0], try only res. Did u try like this

Comment: @PaoloPedrazzi please update your post if you have more details. And more, explain better what you have in the ajax return.

Comment: Nothing change unfortunately

Comment: You've missed `dataType: 'json'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason because you have only one post, is because you put each posts in the same html element *#prova*.

In that way, you are going to have only the last one, as the jQuery method *html()* replace all the code.

You should use the *append()* method instead.

To check, this, just put a debug in the loop, and you will see that there are more posts processed.

And more, an advice, please avoids to put all this html code, it is complicated to read the code.

You should place html in the html page, and use javascript to implement the logic.

Try to use some template engine, like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

**UPDATE:**

You're updating the content by your function *update()* every second through a *setTimeout()* call.

If you want to refresh all the content, and not to add it again (this depends on the details of your ajax call), you should reset the html content of your element on return of the ajax call, just before the loop.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
success: function(data) {
   var $prova = $('#prova');
   $prova.html(''); // reset the current content.
   $.each(data, function(index, value) {
       $prova.append('[... your html code here ...]');
   });  
 }
});
```

Comment: With append it work but every second it append new content from Ajax

Comment: That's because you have setTimeout set to 1000 miliseconds which is one second.So your AJAX call will run every second

Comment: ok, but if i set 60 seconds for example i get every 60 seconds duplicated content because append add new results, i need to check and iterate only if there is new posts from first call

Comment: Thanks!! Working as well. Now i have a problem with alignement of isotope grid. If i put html directly in body alignement is correct. But refreshing content in Ajax return some problems on alignement

Comment: @PaoloPedrazzi you're welcome, about your new issue, please feel free to open a new answer where you details the case.

Answer (score 0):

1.Simly change `res[0]` to `res` inside the `$.each` function.

2.Change  `$('#prova').html()` to  `$('#prova').append()`

Comment: made modifications it return now again 1 record but with "undefined" in text content

Comment: Ok then keep res[0] and just change $('#prova').html() to  $('#prova').append().Does that work?